# How to combine lists that meet certain condition in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, data-manipulation

This might be a lower level question, but I am struggling for an proper answer:
Suppose I have a list (or matrix):

```
{
{{1},{1},{1},{2},{2},{2}},
{{3},{4},{5},{6},{7},{8}}
}
```

And now I want to combine the columns in such a way that the columns with the same first element are combined together, i.e.

```
{
{{1},{2}},
{{3,4,5},{6,7,8}}
}
```

Is there any quick way of realizing this? Sorry for any possible confusions!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
a = {{{1}, {1}, {1}, {2}, {2}, {2}},
     {{3}, {4}, {5}, {6}, {7}, {8}}};

b = GatherBy[Transpose@a, First];
c = DeleteDuplicates@First@a;
d = Array[b[[#, All, 2, 1]] &, Length@c];
{c, d}
```

> {{{1}, {2}}, {{3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8}}}

Comment: +1, but you don't need `Array` I believe; you could use `d = b[[;; Length@c, All, 2, 1]]`.

Answer (score 1):

Chris Degnen already gave a very good method, but I'd like to make a few comments.  It helps to have your data in a format that *Mathematica* functions will most conveniently operate on, and that is usually rows rather than columns.  This is the reason for the `Transpose` in his answer.

*Edit: I think I misunderstood what your output represented.  I have rewritten my answer accordingly.*

Using `GatherBy`, as Chris did:

```
a = {{{1}, {1}, {1}, {2}, {2}, {2}}, {{3}, {4}, {5}, {6}, {7}, {8}}};

{#[[All, 1, 1]], #[[All, All, 2, 1]]} & @ GatherBy[a\[Transpose], First]
```

> ```
> {{{1}, {2}}, {{3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8}}}
> ```

Or using `Sow` and `Reap:`

```
Reap[MapThread[Sow[#2, #] &, a], _, {{#}, Join @@ #2} &][[2]]\[Transpose]
```

> ```
> {{{1}, {2}}, {{3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8}}}
> ```

Here `MapThread` takes the place of the initial `Transpose`.